# what is the difference between /bin and /usr/bin

Tags: directory

Just like the title says, what is the difference between the `/bin` directory and the `/usr/bin` and what are they for?

Answer (score 6):

maybe you can found answer in [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5915/difference-between-bin-and-usr-bin)

based answer on that link, this is the summary:

- `/bin`

> contains commands that may be used by both the system administrator
>   and by users, but which are required when no other filesystems are
>   mounted (e.g. in single user mode). It may also contain commands which
>   are used indirectly by scripts

- `/usr/bin/`

> This is the primary directory of executable commands on the system.